# Design Patterns to Detect Device Types Without Series of Ifs

Tags: design-patterns

I have around 50 types of servers each providing different API/SDK for connection and control.

Given only a server's address, my mission is to write a client program to determine the server's type reasonably quickly.

The tricky part is each of those servers provides drastically different API/SDK for identification. Those API are out of my control. In order to detect the server type, I would naively do something like this:

```
function detectServerType(String address) {

  bool isServerTypeA = proprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeA(address);
  if (isServerTypeA) {
    return "A";
  }

  bool isServerTypeB = proprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeB(address);
  if (isServerTypeB) {
    return "B";
  }

  ...

  bool isServerTypeZ = proprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeZ(address);
  if (isServerTypeZ) {
    return "Z";
  }

} /* This routine takes a long time! */
```

Those servers and `proprietaryRoutine`s are made by different manufacturers and all out of my control. Each server type has to be detected by its unique procedure.

To shorten the time, we may run these checks in parallel.

```
function detectServerType(String address, Callback callbackIfSuccess) {

  callProprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeAInNewThread(address, callbackIfSuccess);
  callProprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeBInNewThread(address, callbackIfSuccess);
  ...
  callProprietaryRoutineToCheckIfTypeZInNewThread(address, callbackIfSuccess);

}
```

This way, I can quickly start checking for all 50 types of servers and run `callbackIfSuccess` as soon as one successful result comes in.

Is there more tried-and-true design pattern when it comes to device identification scenario like this?

Comment: The concurrent approach is good, but just use a loop over a list of predicate functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following things:

1. Create an interface `IServerTypeDetector` with a `detect` function.
2. For each different API/SDK you want to support have a different derived class from the `IServerTypeDetector`.
3. Have a Facade class that will get an address and will run all these different `IServerTypeDetector`s. This class will receive the `IServerTypeDetector`s to execute as dependencies in it's constructor.

*Any questions like: "Should I run in parallel" and similar will be answered in this facade.

In addition maybe instead of returning A/B/C/... according to the type you can return a wrapper sdk of yourself to give your user abstraction from the external sdk that the specific server requires.

Tell me what you think. Hope it helps.

---

Not part of the main issue but I'll add - you can also have a cache of adresses to the abstract/wrapper sdk you return so the second time an adress is given you won't need to execute all the detectors. Here I'd read a bit about Aspect Oriented programming and if you are in C# and usig Castle Windsor then IInterceptors. This way you can keep your code clean from this extra logic.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It seems facade pattern can abstract away the detection procedure from my user. Along with interfaces, the code can be somewhat modular when I implement each server's detection logic one by one. Sounds like a good fit even if the compatibility list grows to hundreds.

Comment: Yes, I have done some AOP using Spring. Now we are moving to Javascript, will definitely need to investigate AOP on Javascript.

Comment: @davidt - Luckily the principals are the same :) good luck

Comment: @davidt - In the Javascript you can make each `IServerTypeDetector` return a promise so it'll run async

Comment: That's great! Clearer and clearer now.